# Избавление от goto

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    List L;
    string x;
    cout << "Bufer is Empty! nn";

    cout << "For the Add Elements Press 'A':n";
    {

        char v = getch();
        if (v == 'a') {
            cout << endl;

            cout << "Enter Elements: n";

          start:
            getline(cin, x);

            L.ElAdd(x);
            cout << "--------n";
        }
        cout << "Elements of Your List:\n\n";
        L.print();
        cout << "--------nn";

        cout << "For the Continue of Adding Press 'P':n";
        cout << "For the Clear Buffer Press 'C':n";
        v = getch();
        if (v == 'p') {
            cout << "Enter the Next Element: n";
            goto start;
        }
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Не могу никак избавиться от goto! Делаю с while, а там зацикливается все! Помогите мне разобраться с этой проблемой. Мне сказали чтобы забыть о goto в дальнейшем, вот и стараюсь уже час. Но ничего не выходит. Как и говорил зацикливается и выводит не то, что я хочу и получал при goto.

Answer (score 4):

Здесь в самый раз подойдет конструкция do->while:

**UPD:**
Надо было посчитать количество открытых и закрытых скобок "{" and "}" и все сразу бы стало ясно:

```
    int main()
{
List L;
string x;
cout << "Bufer is Empty! nn";

cout << "For the Add Elements Press 'A':n";

    char v = getch();
    if (v == 'a') {
        cout << endl;

        cout << "Enter Elements: n";

      do{
        getline(cin, x);

        L.ElAdd(x);
        cout << "--------n";
    cout << "Elements of Your List:\n\n";
    L.print();
    cout << "--------nn";

    cout << "For the Continue of Adding Press 'P':n";
    cout << "For the Clear Buffer Press 'C':n";
    v = getch();
    if (v == 'p') cout << "Enter the Next Element: n";
        }while(true);

        }

system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Я точно так же сделал! Но он не сработал корректно!(

Comment: Что конкретно не получилось?

Comment: Ну вот и на ваш код так же ругается, как и на мой! Вот ошибки:  

1. expected `while' before "cout"   
2. expected `(' before "cout"     
3. expected `)' before ';' token

Comment: Изменил ответ выше.